# How To Make JFrame ..Jbutton to get the input in jtextfield?

Tags: java, user-interface

Im making my project and I want to get the inputs in `jTextField` by pressing the `jButton` then display it it `jLabel`. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You should make an attempt first

Answer (score 0):

Add an action to the button and then in the action handler get the text from textfield element and set the retrieved text as in jlabel element .
Jlabel.settext(jtextfield.gettext().trim());